How to increase the container height?
I want to have something which looks like this, with just month inside

Now, i am having something with which looks like this, please just see the Month part.

I am not able to make that, not able to increase the Container height.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:plates/Helpers/constant.dart';
import 'package:plates/pages/ChartScreen/bloc/chart_screen_bloc.dart';

class MonthButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String month;
  final bool isSelected;
  final VoidCallback onSelect;

  MonthButton(
      {required this.month, required this.isSelected, required this.onSelect});

  @override
  State<MonthButton> createState() => _MonthButtonState();
}

class _MonthButtonState extends State<MonthButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
       //some code
      },
      child: Container(
        width: 100, // Adjust the width according to your requirement
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          border: Border.all(
            color: widget.isSelected
                ? Colors.blueAccent
                : Colors.black, // Apply border color based on selection
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            widget.month,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Try below code:
SizedBox(
      height: 100,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 20,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5,vertical: 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text('Jun'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Text('16'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Text('Mon'),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),

Result: 

No, sir, its not working

oh, crap, it was a Sized box placed in upper elements, thanks
